# What does “sample is considered questionable” mean?

Tags: cosmere, stormlight-archive

In *The Way of Kings*, some of the death rattles have the note “sample is considered questionable” in the description of the subject. Shouldn’t all of the people have

> died in the same hospital?

**Why are some of these quotes “considered questionable?”**

<sub>please tag spoilers for books after *The Way of Kings*</sub>

Comment: There was also "second hand" info. The questionable part is because some of the last words could be "ordinary".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Not all last words are supernatural

Sometimes people say things when they die, even if not compelled by supernatural entities.

There are two death rattles labeled as being "questionable"

> "You've killed me. Bastards, you've killed me! While the sun is still hot, I die! ”
>   — Collected on the fifth day of the week Chach of the month Betab of the year 1171, ten seconds before death. Subject was a darkeyed soldier thirty-one years of age. Sample is considered questionable.

This is a perfectly reasonable thing for a person being killed to say.  It is perhaps a bit dramatic, and the reference to the sun sounds like something from a Shakespearean tragedy, but there is still some question as to whether or not this is truly a death rattle.  There are no references to burning eyes, or unknown names, or anything else that a soldier would be unaware of.

> "The death is my life, the strength becomes my weakness, the journey has ended."
>   — Dated Betabanes, 1173, 95 seconds pre-death. Subject: a scholar of some minor renown. Sample collected secondhand. Considered questionable.

This quote is suspicious because it was said by a scholar.  When an "illiterate Herdazian" produces a perfect ketek, it's unusual.  When a scholar references a famous oath, it's less so (even if the oath has drifted into obscurity, it's still being repeated by a *scholar*.  They tend to specialize in obscure quotes).  The fact that the quote was collected secondhand only makes the verification trickier.